# Is there a list of graphics cards ordered by relative performance?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, benchmarking

I'm struggling to make sense of graphics card manufacturers' cryptic names and codes for their products.

For example, some cards with a higher number or code in the name are actually *less* powerful than those with a lower number. Then there are the prefixes and suffixes, and the fact that NVIDIA has an entirely different naming scheme to AMD.

Is there a big list of graphics card models ordered by relative performance? It doesn't have to be a precise benchmark, just an overview so I can get some idea of what is more powerful than what.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you are looking for this list

http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/gaming-graphics-card-review,3107.html

Specifically

http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/gaming-graphics-card-review,3107-7.html

There is a new version every 1-2 months

Comment: That's brilliant, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you want an ongoing list of video card performance figures then Passmark's [Videocard Benchmarks](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net) site lists just about every video card out there with an easy ordered list where you can see their relative performance.

Answer (score 1):

For mobile graphics cards, check out notebookcheck.net's [Comparison of Laptop Graphics Cards](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Comparison-of-Laptop-Graphics-Cards.130.0.html).

They also have two complementary lists which give more details, about [benchmark results](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Mobile-Graphics-Cards-Benchmark-List.844.0.html) and [game performance](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Computer-Games-on-Laptop-Graphic-Cards.13849.0.html), respectively. Both can also be configured to list desktop cards, which are hidden by default.